# Binary file not found

Tags: c, binaryfiles

The program shows no errors or warnings, but the only problem is that I cannot find the ".bin" file where the data is being saved.
The C file is saved on my Windows desktop, but still, when I compile it, I can't find the bin file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

FILE *bfile;
int i;

bfile=fopen("bfile.bin","bw");

for(i=2;i<=500;i+=2)
    fwrite(i, sizeof(int),1,bfile);
}
```

Comment: Compiling it will have no effect. You need to *run* it.

Comment: This program will create `bfile.bin` in the current working directory - *ie* the directory you were in when you ran the executable.

Comment: I run it ,but still I don't find the file. Can you run it on your computer please?

Comment: The file will be closed by the implicit `exit()` from `main()` returning.  It's not good to do it that way, but the file will be closed and the pending output flushed.  The code does not check that the file was opened, but would probably crash if it was not.  It would be best in the short term to try creating the file with an absolute pathname.  I expect the file is being created in some peculiar directory from which the executable is being run.

Answer (score 1):

2 problems; 1) the b flag needs to be after the w

```
fopen("bfile.bin","wb")
```

and 2) fwrite takes a pointer, change i to &i

```
fwrite(&i,sizeof(int),1,bfile);
```

Actually according the 'man fopen' the b is ignored on POSIX.

Comment: Good catch on the pointer. Interesting that the OP's original code didn't segfault with the missing `&`